# Unable to switch login after dropping a server 2012r2 from domain

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I need someone to help me rejoin a server to our domain. After removing a server from the domain, when the server restarts, there is no option to log in as another user/local user.

Details:

While setting up a VM I inadvertently broke the trust of a different server 2012 r2 with the domain.

Logged on as local administrator.

Deleted role security certification.

Deleted computer from domain AD.

Logged on as local administrator.

Removed the server from the domain / joined a "WORKGROUP".

Rebooted

Now only prompted to log in as the domain administrator which is not a local account/user.

Can't log on as a different user because there's no option to do that.

Comment: There is no switch user option.  The back arrow takes you back to the lock screen, "Press Ctl+Alt+Del" to log in.  I'm only presented with the one user "Comp221guru" which is the domain administrator account.  Not a local account.  I have two active local accounts, Administrator and Joe.  Neither are presented or an option on the log in screen.  They were before I left the domain and joined the workgroup.  But not after the reboot.

Comment: Can't RDP into it, can't // connect to it, restarting it in SafeMode still prompts me to use the Comp221guru account.
It makes sense that when I dropped it from the domain, it took the domain admin (Comp221guru) username and made it local... but... o. O

Answer (score 1):

Did you try logging on using .\administrator ? Putting a ".\" before username tells your computer to use the local user account.

Comment: So that's the crux of my problem, at the sign in screen, I'm not able to change the username. It's automatically trying to sign in as that domain admin account. I'm stuck with that username, which won't authenticate, because it's off the domain! Just not sure how to force switch a user sign on.

Comment: Does it show it like "DomainName\username" ? You can also try to connect to \\VM_Ip_Address\c$ with local user account credentials (it will ask you) to make sure that the local user account is still there and active.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Ws5Nqzx.jpg?1

Comment: That's probably the only local user account you have now. Maybe there's policy in your domain that renames local administrator account? Try local admin's password with that user.

Comment: I have(had?) two local accounts, Administrator and Joe.
I tried using either one's password for the domain admin (Comp221guru) with no luck. :/

Comment: Did you try connecting to \\VM_Ip_Address\c$ ? Does it work?

Comment: Nope, credentials didn't work, either with using the local usernames (Administrator & Joe) or the domain admin (Comp221guru) with any of those passwords. :/

Comment: Are you sure that there's no company policy handles local users? Because it seems like your local users are gone. Anyway, you can try [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/96630/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-windows-password-the-easy-way/) to add a new local user and add him to the local Administrators group , or to see if your local users are still there and reset their passwords. Your Windows folder will probably be in D: drive after booting from DVD/ISO. Change the paths in those copy commands accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Mer! I'll give it a try. I appreciate your assistance.